# How to define style resources for specific control in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am newbie to Xamarin and Xamarin.Form, basically I want to define style for the controls.

Like when I place Label control then it should follow the same style throughout the page. I've read somewhere on article that it can be done by defining styles in  tags but don't know how..

1. How to define for 1 page
2. How to define globally which will be applied to all the pages
3. How to define device specific

Can anyone provide some example code / link for same?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about doing it through XAML then:
- if it is per page then go with [resources](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/xaml-for-xamarin-forms/xaml_markup_extensions/).
- for device specific, use [OnPlatform](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/xaml-for-xamarin-forms/essential_xaml_syntax/) class
- there are no global resources currently

If you are creating your stuff in code then apply whatever global value you wish when you create them. If there are platform specific values then use [Device class](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/platform-specifics/).
HTH

Comment: I've already reviewed those link but that doesn't suffice my question. for e.g. I have 50 labels on my page, and for all the 50 labels it should apply the same style.

Comment: Well, you can still "postprocess" XAML after it has initialized and walk the view hierarchy and applying properties that way. Would that do for you?

Answer (score -1):

For per page resources, you can create a Common folder with files such as "ColorResources" which might have entries such as

```
public static readonly Color ActivityIndicator = Color.Blue;
```

You can then use that in your XAML like this

```
<ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsLoading}" 
  Color="{x:Static common:ColorResources.ActivityIndicator}" />
```

(Remember to declare your common namespace)

For cross page, I'd recommend a custom renderer, built from the original control but tailored to look like what you want.  You can find out more here[Custom Renderers](http://blog.falafel.com/learning-xamarin-custom-renderers-in-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: I want to apply for each control directly instead of applying static resource or any other resource with each control.